# Accessing configuration default values in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient / more compact way to do this.  I have a configuration class instance where all the state is optional.  It looks like this.  I have a constructor like this (StoreConfig is pasted below):

```
constructor(config?:StoreConfig) {
    config = config ? config : new StoreConfig();

}
```

Now just use the config with the default value getters.

```
/**
 * Store configuration.
 */
export class StoreConfig {
  static ID_KEY_DEFAULT:string = 'id';
  static GUID_KEY_DEFAULT:string = 'gid';

  constructor(private _idKey?:string, private _guidKey?:string) {};

  get idKey():string {
    return  this._idKey ? this._idKey : StoreConfig.ID_KEY_DEFAULT;
  }
  get guidKey():string {
    return this.guidKey ? this.guidKey : StoreConfig.GUID_KEY_DEFAULT;
  }
}
```

Comment: you could assign a default value to both your constructor arguments and avoid the ternary in your getters

Comment: I was thinking about doing that, but then the constructor argument cannot be optional ... Any ideas on how to get around that?

Comment: An argument with a default value is optional, even though it is not written with a question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a default value for your constructor arguments, like so:

```
export class StoreConfig {
  constructor(
    private _idKey: string = "id",
    private _guidKey: string = "gid"
  ) {}

  get idKey(): string {
    return this._idKey
  }
  get guidKey(): string {
    return this._guidKey
  }
}
```

by providing a default value you're letting Typescript know this is an optional argument that falls back to its default value.

then it doesn't complain about missing arguments when you do this:

`const x = new StoreConfig()`

Comment: I tested it - It's a nice solution.  The only difference is that we have to either leave the defaults or assign both parameters if the second on one needs a different value and the first value can stay the same, because null cannot be assigned to the first one.

Comment: true, not perfect. try passing an object and merging it with your defaults.

Comment: Great idea - Object.assign() should do the trick...Maybe Typescript Partial as well.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working pretty well for the [general design](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/slice) I was going for:

```
export const STORE_CONFIG_DEFAULT: StoreConfig = {
  idKey: "id",
  guidKey: "gid"
};

Object.freeze(STORE_CONFIG_DEFAULT);

export class StoreConfig {
  public idKey: string;
  public guidKey: string;
  constructor(c?: Partial<StoreConfig>) {
    let config = Object.assign({ ...STORE_CONFIG_DEFAULT }, c);
    this.idKey = config.idKey;
    this.guidKey = config.guidKey;
  }
}
```

Some other classes can now rely on STORE_CONFIG_DEFAULT for the default configuration.